# найти значение ячейки таблицы

Tags: jquery

Таблица. [получить значение ячейки](https://jsfiddle.net/kley/d81n04oo/)

```
<div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Номенклатура</th>
                        <th>Ед.изм</th>
                        <th>Мин</th>
                        <th>Средн</th>
                        <th>Макс</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="t_price">
          <tr>
            <td>
            <button type="button" class="add_item btn btn-primary btn-sm">+</button></td>
            <td>Кофе1</td>
            <td>кг</td>
            <td>300</td>
            <td>400</td>
            <td>500</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><button type="button" class="add_item btn btn-primary btn-sm">+</button></td>
            <td>Кофе2</td>
            <td>уп</td>
            <td>350</td>
            <td>470</td>
            <td>600</td> 
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td><button type="button" class="add_item btn btn-primary btn-sm">+</button></td>
             <td>Кофе3</td>
             <td>г</td>
             <td>110</td>
             <td>200</td>
             <td>350</td> 
           </tr>
         </tbody>
         </table>
         </div>
            </table>
        </div>
```

В самой первой ячейке кнопка "+". по нажатию на плюс нужно получить в данной строке текст колонки "Номенклатура"

js:

```
$('#t_price').on('click','.add_item',function(){
        var it=$(this).next('td').html();
            console.log(it);
        });
```

результат почему-то undefined. в чем подвох?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подвох в том, что у кнопки нет *следующего* элемента, поэтому `$(this).next('td')` вернет пустой селектор.

Для исправления, нужно использовать, например, [`parent`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

```
var it=$(this).parent().next('td').html();
```

Comment: да. все получилось. я не додумалась. спасибо